# Migration from 4.3 sdk to ios 5 sdk

Tags: migration, ios5

I just updated my old ios 4.3 sdk working project to ios 5 sdk and I'm retrieving the following error:

> ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Any clue of what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was missing a library that in ios 4.3 was called libz.1.2.3.dylib but now on ios 5 the lib is called: libz.1.2.5.dylib.

Problem solved.

Comment: I have the same problem, except for missing the 1.2.5 version when building for ios5, I dont know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of linking against `libz.1.2.3.dylib` or `libz.1.2.5.dylib`, link against `libz.dylib`.  This will always be the latest version of libz.